# Update to 15.10 breaks networking

Tags: networking, upgrade, xubuntu

I upgraded two XUbuntu machines from 15.04 to 15.10. After the upgrade, the first machine no longer had working Ethernet.

For the second machine I used [this post](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/#idontlikethishowdoidisablethis) and followed the first option:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

The second machine's networking worked fine after the upgrade.

I want to restore `eth0` to the first machine. Right now it shows devices `virbr0` and `eno16777735`, both of which are disabled. What must I do?